# Problem Nvidia Driver with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I installed Nvidia driver on my laptop, but when i execute `nvidia-smi` , i got this error:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Installed Driver : `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455`

Kernel : `Linux 5.4.0-47-generic`

Selected GPU : `sudo prime-select nvidia`

Log :

```
`cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log  log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log 
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot 
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px  
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.4.0-47-generic/updates/dkms 
Found nvidia module: nvidia.ko 
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.4.0-47-generic/updates/dkms 
Is nvidia loaded? yes 
Was nvidia unloaded? no 
Is nvidia blacklisted? no 
Is intel loaded? yes Is radeon loaded? no 
Is radeon blacklisted? no 
Is amdgpu loaded? no 
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no 
Is amdgpu versioned? no 
Is amdgpu pro stack? no 
Is nouveau loaded? no 
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes 
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes 
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no 
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:166 BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0" Is boot vga? yes Vendor/Device Id: 10de:de3 BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0" Is boot vga? no Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver The device is not bound to any driver. 
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915" Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915" 
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915" 
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915" output 0:  card0-LVDS-1 Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1 
Does it require offloading? yes 
last cards number = 2 
Has amd? no 
Has intel? yes 
Has nvidia? yes 
How many cards? 2 
Has the system changed? No 
Intel IGP detected Intel hybrid system 
Creating /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf 
Setting power control to "on" in /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control 
Loading nvidia with "no" parameters`
```

Any idea to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you reboot after installing the new 455 driver?  That sometimes helps.

Comment: Yes i reboot after installing but the problem not resolving

Comment: Please add the contents of /var/log/gpu-manager.log to your question to provide more information.  How did you get the 455 drivers?  They are now a part of the standard repos, so no ppa or direct-from-nvidia download necessary.

Comment: I added the log in description, i installed driver from standard repos

Comment: The nvidia blacklisted=yes is a problem.  Check the /etc/modprobe.d directory for any file blacklisting nvidia.  nvidiafb is OK to blacklist.

Comment: I fixed the problem of nvidia blacklist but still same error

Comment: Plesse repost the gpu-manager.log now that nvidia is no longer blacklisted. Also, try updating everything, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade   That will rebuild the nvidia module watch for any errors in the text output.

Comment: I repost the gpu-manager.log, I try apt-get update and dist-upgrade, the problem still same

Comment: 5.0.4-54 is the current 20.04 kernel, and your log still refers to 5.4.0-47. Did you reboot after the upgrade to run the new kernel?

Comment: yes it's my default kernel already, i haven't installed any upgrade.

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: The 455 driver just hit the standard repos, so upgrading to the latest kernels seemed like the best idea to me to eliminate possible incompatibility problems. If you don't want to upgrade to the latest, maybe try the older 450 or even the 440 drivers.

Comment: I tried another driver like 450, 390 and 440, the same problem, I upgraded also the kernel to the latest and other problem appear like the system not boot properly. I can't understand the root cause.

Comment: Googling the phrase device is not bound to any driver there are lots of similar problems.  See https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2377560.html for one proposed solution.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks for your support :)